# Expected number of assignments to find maximum value in an array

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, max, analysis

In the following Java code:

```
int max = arr[0];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
         max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

How many times does the line `max = arr[i];` run assuming that the array is unsorted.

Comment: every time it will find a value in array lesser than max value.

Comment: But there must be a numerical expected number of times it runs

Comment: That code is for the minimum, not the maximum.

Comment: sorry - got the > the wrong way

Answer (score 5):

Expected valued can be computated via linearity of expectations. I could provide a more rigorous answer if this site supported MathJax.

The answer is sum 1/(n-i+1) for i = 1 to n = sum 1/i for i = 1 to n = O(log n) where n is the size of the array (assuming all elements of the array are distinct)

Warning, Math-sy part ahead.

The key idea is that if we assign each element a lexicographical index   'i' where 'i' denotes that the element is the 'i'th smallest element, then an assignment will happen only if none of the n-i+1 larger elements apprar before the ith element in the array. The probability that this happens in a random array is 1/(n-i+1) for all i. Then we just apply linearity of expectations using an indicator random variable :)